# Using several pom files to build a project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have two distinct complex build task which must be done sequentially by maven. For example creating war files, library and ...

As far as I know, I have to split these tasks into separate maven pom files. By this approach, each pom file has a specific responsibility, I can keep them as simple as possible and above all, as a result of some technical issues, I have to do this.
I put shared dependencies between these two files in a parent pom file to reduce duplication. 
In this case create-jar.xml and create-war.xml are tasks and parent.xml contains shared dependencies.

*parent.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>main</groupId>
        <artifactId>main</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.13</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </project>
```

*create-jar.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>main</artifactId>
        <groupId>main</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>parent.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>create</groupId>
    <artifactId>create</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

*create-war.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>main</artifactId>
        <groupId>main</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>parent.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>create-war</groupId>
    <artifactId>create-war</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**What I need is to call *mvn install* of both pom files by one command. The Order is really important for me as create-jar must run before create-war.**

There are two approaches.

First *inheritance*, By using create-jar.xml as a direct parent of create-war.xml, therefore by running create-war, create-jar is called.

The other solution is *composition* by running create-jar.xml from create-war.xml. I'm not sure how can I do that. But I think maven-invoker or maven-antRun plugins can be helpful.
I'd be happy to give me a hand.

Comment: What i anderstand is that you Need a Multi module build

Comment: Please clarify if your WAR shall include the JAR. If your scenario really is, "build a JAR, then, build a WAR containing the JAR"- you are most probably not the first with this scenario.

Comment: I would try adding this to your create-war.xml
    `<modules>
        <module>main</module>
        <module>create</module>
    </modules>`

Answer (score 0):

Check this [sample project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html).
Basically you will need a parent pom which will call your 2 child poms.
The above example is a bit long but they will explain each and every step in layman's term.